# The smallest non-abelian group $G$ with a non-normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

This time I need to find the smallest non-abelian group $G$ with a non-normal subgroup, then my questions are:

1)Can someone help me to find it?

2)Once we find it, How Can you prove that it is the smallest one ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What have you done on this problem so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up to and including order $5$ there are no non-abelian groups at all. So, we start at order $6$.

So, then we find as the first candidate group $S_3$, the permutation group of $\{1,2,3\}$. 
We consider its nontrivial subgroups, there are some of order $2$ and one of order $3$. Turns out the ones of order $2$ are not normal.

---

If you do not know the result mentioned in the first line, you can argue like this: since for $H$ a subgroup of $G$ we have the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$ a group of order $1,2,3,5$ has no nontrivial subgroups at all (and the group itself as well as the subgroup just formed by the identity element are clealry normal).

It remains to consider groups of order $4$. A subgroup of order $2$ has index two and thus is also normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) and how do you prove it is the smallest one ?

Comment: You are welcome. As I said there are no non-abelian groups of order less than $6$ so it is clear that an example of order $6$ is the smallest possible.

Comment: Ok then that is the only thing I have to argue :)

Comment: Yes. And to show this, you can invoke the fact that  cylcic groups are  the only groups of prime order, and then are left to consider groups of order $4$ only, of which there are two. Possibly you know this, if not distinguish case on existence of an element of order $4$.

Comment: mmmm well I don't understand the above comment very well

Comment: For a prime $p$ there is exactly one type of group of that order namely the cyclic group with $p$ elements; this is not hard to prove from Lagrange's theorem for example. For order $4$ groups, if there is an element of order $4$ it is cyclic as generated by that element, if not all elements have order at most $2$ and you get the Klein four group. On second thought however there is a better argument that I will edit into the body of thhe post.

Comment: Ok Ill apreciate it ;) a lot thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$G=S_3\;,\;\;H=\{(1)\;,\;\;(12)\} .\;\text{Then}\;\;H\le G\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;H\rlap{\;\;/}\lhd G$$

You now prove this is the smallest example of what you want.

Comment: Well In fact I don't know how to prove that this is the smallest one :(

Comment: This is basic group theory: prove that **any** group of order $\,\le5\;$ is abelian, and that there is a non-abelian group of order six.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot anyway :)